# Internet Explorer Blown Up Image Issues

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, joomla

Hello on my website I have been developing a "Consultant" section and on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox the image is the correct size but in Internet Explorer it's blown up really large to nearly a full screen image.

Comment: What version are you using? I'm testing in IE 8 and it's very enlarged.

Comment: IE 8 !?! released 2009 - how about upgrading?